# Wildfly Clustering using JBoss

Tags: wildfly, jgroups, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to set up a Wildfly 11 cluster but I'm not able to make it work. Basically, I have 2 instances of Wildfly with one instance having port-offset=2 running on my local machine. Here are the publisher and MDB:

```
@JMSDestinationDefinitions(value = { @JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "java:/topic/CLUSTEREVENTTOPIC", interfaceName = "javax.jms.Topic", destinationName = "ClusterEventTopic") })
@Stateless
public class ClusterEventPublisher implements Serializable {
```

MDB

```
@MessageDriven(name = "ClusterEventMonitor", activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "topic/CLUSTEREVENTTOPIC"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
public class ClusterEventMonitor implements MessageListener {
```

Note that I'm able to see this topic created on Wildfly, but when I publish a message on the topic. It's only read by the node that sends the message.

For example:
node1 sends an eventDto as the message, node1 will receive the message but not node2.

Note that I'm using standalone-full-ha.xml configuration. I just added the following line in ActiveMQ module:

```
<cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:opencell}"/>
```

Full config is downloadable from, note that the second instance has exactly the same configuration with the only difference being the port-offset value:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ttyb05dx7cps21/standalone-full-ha-test.xml

I'm on debug mode and sure that the message doesn't reach node2. Any idea?

Comment: Are both instances running from same machine?

Comment: I tried running 2 instances of WF on the same machine with different node name using localhost, private interface. I also tried using public interface, binding the WF instance to network IP (192.x..) but the same result. When I look at the ClusterEventTopic in Wildfly management interface, subscription count is always 1 for both with different messages count. Does that mean they have different isolated JMS?

Comment: Can you share the subscription and message count screenshot for both the nodes

Comment: They have a different count. 5 in node1 and 2 in node 2. I'll answer my question in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now able to receive the message send from node1 via JMS in node2. However, I really did not do anything. I compared my configuration files and they are almost the same with my first set of nodes that don't work. What I did was just download a new Wildfly 11 zipped, do the necessary database configuration and it worked. For those asking, here's part of my standalone-full-ha.xml config:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:5.0">
    <channels default="ee">
        <channel name="ee" stack="udp" cluster="ejb"/>
    </channels>
    <stacks>
        <stack name="udp">
            <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
            <protocol type="PING"/>
            <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
            <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="UFC"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
        </stack>
        <stack name="tcp">
            <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
            <socket-protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
            <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
            <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
        </stack>
    </stacks>
</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:secret}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

As for infinispan cache:

```
<cache-container name="projectx">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <replicated-cache name="projectx-cache" mode="SYNC">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="100000"/>
    </replicated-cache>
```

And ActiveMQ

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:secret}"/>
```

Make sure that you bind your server to your IP address or 0.0.0.0 for testing.

Comment: Did you receive the message on one node, or both nodes? What I'm trying to achieve is receiving the MDB in all nodes, but I get it on only one.